# Secure Random hex digits only

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to generate random digits with SecureRandom class of rails. Can we create a random number with SecureRandom.hex which includes only digits and no alphabets.

For example:

Instead of

```
SecureRandom.hex(4)
=> "95bf7267"
```

It should give

```
SecureRandom.hex(4)
=> "95237267"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the api for SecureRandom: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html

I believe you're looking for a different method: #random_number.

```
SecureRandom.random_number(a_big_number)
```

Since #hex returns a hexadecimal number, it would be unusual to ask for a random result that contained only numerical characters.

For basic use cases, it's simple enough to use #rand.

```
rand(9999)
```

Edited:

I'm not aware of a library that generates a random number of specified length, but it seems simple enough to write one. Here's my pass at it:

```
def rand_by_length(length)
  rand((9.to_s * length).to_i).to_s.center(length, rand(9).to_s).to_i
end
```

The method #rand_by_length takes an integer specifying length as a param and tries to generate a random number of max digits based on the length. String#center is used to pad the missing numbers with random number characters. Worst case calls #rand for each digit of specified length. That may serve your need.

Comment: Thanks for correcting on "hexadecimal number"
I would like to explain it further, I was actually looking for a random number with specific length(lets say 8), hex does restricts the length so wondering something similar, SecureRandom might have that would generate numbers only.
SecureRandom.random_number(n) probably wont allow this ?
[random_number](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html#M000733)

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric id's are good because they are easier to read over the phone (no c for charlie).

Try this

```
length = 20
id = (SecureRandom.random_number * (10**length)).round.to_s # => "98075825200269950976"
```

and for bonus points break it up for easier reading

```
id.split(//).each_slice(4).to_a.map(&:join).join('-') # => "9807-5825-2002-6995-0976"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a number of the desired length.

```
length = 11

rand(10**length..(10**length+1)-1).to_s
```

Answer (score -1):

```
length = 4

[*'0'..'9'].sample(length).join
```

as simple as that :)

Comment: My 1 cent: Without the splat `(0..9).to_a.sample(length).join`

Comment: @swap.nil why is it better?

Comment: This does not work for desired lengths > 10. Also this will use every number only once.